# How to prove the skew symmetry of the Riemannian tensor?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, tensors

I parallel transported a vector around a parallelogram formed by another two vectors to get the Riemannian tensor:

$$R^m{}_{lkj} = \left( \partial_k \Gamma^m{}_{jl} + \Gamma^m{}_{kn} \Gamma^n{}_{jl} \right)
- \left( \partial_j \Gamma^m{}_{kl} + \Gamma^m{}_{jn} \Gamma^n{}_{kl} \right)
$$

The difference between the two terms is the exchange of $j$ and $k$ indexes.
So the skew symmetry of the last two indices ($R^m{}_{lkj} = -R^m{}_{ljk} $) are immediately apparent.

But it isn't immediately obvious to me why there is a skew symmetry in the first two indices too, so

$$R^m{}_{lkj} = -R^l{}_{mkj} $$

How can one prove that this symmetry indeed hold?

Comment: This symmetry is only true when you lower the upper indices, no?

Comment: @TedShifrin But I can lower it then raise it again can't I?

Comment: @Calmarius That would give $R^m_{\;lkj}=R^{\;m}_{l\;kj}$. You can't have a up index on one side have the same letter as a down index on the other side.

Comment: @OscarCunningham Hmmm, then it's possible that symmetry only there when all indexes are lowered. I'll try to see what happens, if I lower it.